# Laravel pluck related model not getting result

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working inside a Laravel 9 project that uses the Laravel spatie permissions package. I need to return my permissions on my `Role` as an array, I've tried the following query:

```php
Role::with(['permissions' => function ($query) {
  $query->pluck('name')->select('name');
}])->find(2);
```

This is what my current data structure looks like. Note that `model` is just my return from my controller.

```json
{
    "model": {
        "id": 2,
        "company_id": 1,
        "name": "admin",
        "guard_name": "api",
        "created_at": "2023-02-09T15:14:42.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-09T15:14:42.000000Z",
        "permissions": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "user_index",
                "guard_name": "api",
                "created_at": "2023-02-09T15:14:42.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-02-09T15:14:42.000000Z",
                "pivot": {
                    "role_id": 2,
                    "permission_id": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "user_show",
                "guard_name": "api",
                "created_at": "2023-02-09T15:14:42.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-02-09T15:14:42.000000Z",
                "pivot": {
                    "role_id": 2,
                    "permission_id": 2
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And this is my desired output:

```json
{
    "model": {
        "id": 2,
        "company_id": 1,
        "name": "admin",
        "guard_name": "api",
        "created_at": "2023-02-09T15:14:42.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-09T15:14:42.000000Z",
        "permissions": [
            "user_index",
            "user_show"
        ]
    }
}
```

Here's my controller function:

```php
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $this->authorize('view', Role::class);

    $role = Role::with('permissions')->find($id);

    if (!$role) {
        return new ApiSuccessResponse(null, [
            'message' => 'Role not found or invalid role ID.'
        ], 404);
    }

    return new ApiSuccessResponse($role);
}
```

Comment: Interesting; I'll have to play with that query to see why it doesn't return what is expected. Sidenote, you could also use an `appends` method to reduce `permissions: [{name: 'user_index', ...}, {name: 'user_show', ...}]` to `permissions: ['user_index', 'user_show']`, since you're casting this Model to JSON for your API response: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: Yeah, `->pluck()` doesn't work there, at all. `->select('name')` will reduce it from the whole Model to `'permissions': [{'name': 'user_index'}, {'name':'user_show'}]`, but you'll probably still need to use another approach to "pluck" that array to just `'permissions': ['user_index, 'user_show']`.

Comment: How? I've tried an implementation which isn't giving me the desired result.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75402140/edit) and show this new implementation, then we should be able to help further. When you try something new and it doesn't work, show that, so we don't have to start from scratch again to help you...